# Hadoop, uneven load between machines

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing

I have a cluster of 4 machines that I need to run a benchmark against.

I decide to use Terasort to benchmark.

However, when I run the benchmark, only one out of four machine is under load, while the other three are completely idle.

If I run the test another time, a different machine would be completely under load while the other three would be idle.

When I create the dataset with Teragen everything works just fine, the load is evenly distributed between all the four machine.

What can be wrong in this configuration ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope your cluster is distributed properly as 4 nodes (1 name node , 1 secondary name node, 2 data nodes)

The process flow happens like it starts with name-node and job tracker will schedule the job for the task trackers which has the data blocks.

The usage of data-nodes depends on few factors like number of replication, number of mappers and number of blocks.

If The number of blocks are many, it will be placed evenly in all the data nodes of your cluster. If the replication factor is 2, then the blocks will be available in both the data nodes. So both can run the mappers which deal with those blocks

If you have two blocks for a file and two mappers will run simultaneously in the data nodes and utilize the resources properly.

In your case, it seems block size is the problem. Try to reduce it. so  there should be at least 2 blocks which makes utilization will be more and so is the performance.

Hadoop can be tuned as per your need with the below settings.

```
dfs.replication in hdfs-site.xml
dfs.block.size in hdfs-site.xml
```

Good luck !!!

Comment: The file is quite large and I have like  50 blocks, each is replicated on 3 different machines, it isn't enough ?